# Can't upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 due to apt version

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates, 22.04, do-release-upgrade

I don't seem to be able to upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04.1 LTS due to my apt version, but it's also up to date.

I've run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

and all packages appear to be up to date.

However, when I run `sudo do-release-upgrade`, it fails with the error

```
Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done

Required depends are not installed 

The required dependency 'apt (>= 2.0.4)' is not installed.
```

Running `apt --version` does indeed give `apt 2.0.2 (amd64)`.

Checking the versions of apt available on focal here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt appears to indicate that 2.0.2 is the latest available on the `release (main)` branch, although 2.0.9 is available under `updates (main)`.

Is it possible to install the 2.0.9 version somehow? How can I get `do-release-upgrade` to work?

Comment: try downloading .deb and installing it: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/amd64/apt/download

Comment: what is the output from `sudo apt install apt` ?

Comment: Show the output of `apt list apt`. Let's verify whether you have `-security` enabled or not.

Comment: Have you tried following these steps? https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/upgrade-ubuntu-20-04-lts-to-22-04-lts/

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you've said what package you actually have installed; the expected would be `apt | 2.0.2ubuntu0.2  | focal-security  | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` or `apt | 2.0.9           | focal-updates   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` but you seem to concentrated on version the app displays, where package tools use the package version.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. @user535733 `apt list apt` gives `apt/focal,now 2.0.2 amd64 [installed]`
 `apt/focal 2.0.2 i386`

Comment: hm, I see my `/etc/apt/sources.list` only lists `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal multiverse main universe restricted`, so I guess I would need to add a line for `focal-updates` in order to get the 2.0.9 version?

Answer (score 5):

**Uh-oh. You have bigger problems.**

- Your version of apt: 2.0.2 (focal)
- Version of apt in the focal-security repo: 2.0.2ubuntu0.2
- Version of apt in the focal-updates pocket: 2.0.9

The difference in versions suggests two problems:

1. You disabled `focal-security`. **BAD. Don't do that.** It means you have been running unpatched against known, published vulnerabilities. Perhaps for years. This is a get-your-system-off-the-internet(now!) kind of mistake.

   It's possible that your insecure system may be compromised. The usual recommendation is to reinstall Ubuntu to eliminate any malware or backdoors that an intruder may have placed on your insecure system without your knowledge.
2. You disabled `focal-updates`. Some folks make this mistake when they try to disable update notifications. But it means that you did not receive the newer version of apt that you now need.

   The usual recommendation is to simply re-enable `-updates`, then run `sudo apt update`, then `sudo apt upgrade`. This will provide all the upgrades required to bring your 20.04 system to readiness for a release-upgrade to 22.04. **However**, you already need to reinstall Ubuntu anyway. The failure to install timely security upgrades is more important.

**What you should do today**: Install Ubuntu 22.04 from a LiveUSB instead of a release-upgrade from an insecure 20.04 system.

**Going Forward**:

- NEVER disable `-security` without a good (temporary) reason
- DON'T disable `-updates`. There are better ways to stop update notifications.

Comment: FWIW, if you run `grep -E "^deb.*\-(security|updates)" -r /etc/apt` and get output like "/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http:\/gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http:\/security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted" (swapped / for \ to avoid linkifying) then you have the -updates and -security repos enabled.

Answer (score 3):

As @user535733 has [referenced](https://askubuntu.com/a/1429370/547057), the issue was that my `/etc/apt/sources.list` only had an entry for

`deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal multiverse main universe restricted`.

Editing it to read

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse main universe restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

has fixed the issue, although you are then left with the security implications mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the solution was very simple. Just switch "**Subscribed to**" in the GUI from "**Security updates only**" to "**Security and recommended updates**".

[Screenshot of Security & Updates -> Updates GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHmfS.png)

Running `apt update` after that resulted in lots of software updates (including apt 2.0.2 -> 2.0.9).